# Jquery function should also work with other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make this function working multiple times:

- Currently works only with the h1 tag
- how can I make it working for the `<div class="logo">` as well? I don't want to repeat the function, I need a way to make the function working for various elements.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/33Ec8/4/

JS:

```
// Get the divs that should change
function displayThese() {
    var $heading = $('h1');
    var h1top = $heading.position().top;
    var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();
    var h1left = $heading.position().left;
    var h1right = h1top + $heading.width();

    var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
        var $e = $(this);
        var top = $e.position().top;
        var bottom = top + $e.height();
        var left = $e.position().left;
        var right = left + $e.width();

        return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top || left > h1right || right < h1left;
    });
    return divs;
}

(function fadeInDiv() {
    var divs = displayThese();
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.animate({
            opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
        });
    }

})();

$(window).resize(function () {
    // Get items that do not change    
    var divs = $('li').not(displayThese());
    divs.css({
        opacity: 0.3
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried passing your selector to the function?

Comment: i can't actualy replicate your function at all from your code (it does nothing), but could you not use h1 && .logo?

Comment: @jack could you please help? not sure how?

Comment: Take a look at Kimball Robinson answer for an example of what I was describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't stated very clearly, so I would strongly suggest describing what the code should do vs what it does.

That said, here is a half-blind attempt at answering what I think you want.

You could pass in the selector as a parameter to displayThese.

```
function displayThese(selectorString)
{
     var $elementsUnderWhichNothingShouldFade = $(selectorString);
     ...
}
```

then when you call displayThese, you can pass in any complex selector you like.

```
var divsToChange = displayThese('h1, div.logo')
```

Of course, you would need to add extra logic to test whether the image elements were underneath *any* of the resulting $elementsUnderWhichNothingShouldFade (which is a list of elements).

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to explain better that I could! I simply need to be able to use it for various elements, not just th h1 tag. like you said, I'm now trying to make it working with your code:-)

Comment: thanks for this! http://jsfiddle.net/33Ec8/7/ is this what you have in mind? which extra logic you are referring?

Comment: @user3699998, The extra logic I am referring to is your job to figure out.  If I just hand you the answer, I am not helping you learn.  What kind of experience do you have writing software?  Who are you doing this project for?  How much do you want to learn programming, and how deep do you want to go?

Comment: ok, gotcha. Sorry I was only keen on understanding where I could improve my code! as on my fiddle the h1 tag now is not working. I can see animations underneath:-(

Comment: var divs = displayThese('h1, div.logo'); doesn't work. woks only one. any idea why?

Comment: @user3699998, The reason your h1 element is now allowing animations underneath is that when you are getting the .top(), .left() and so on, you are doing it for the last element in the list.  You need to get the borders of *each* element in the resulting list.

Comment: Would u be able to help me please?

Comment: Make a list of candidate elements to "display" (fade).  Loop through each element to avoid (see the jquery each() function), and inside that loop through each candidate.  If the candidate appears under the current element, remove it from the list of elements to "display" (or inversely, only add it to a new list of displayableElements if it passes every test -- this would require switching which loop is the outer loop).